# Error with dates and reactive inputs in R Shiny

Tags: r, date, shiny

I am putting together a small R Shiny app which will take several inputs from the user and use these inputs to subset a data frame and provide back two histograms.  The users will pick a baseball season, two teams and then this information will provide a reactive list of possible games played between these two teams. The user will then pick a date/game and then a histogram will be displayed for each team which will show the distribution of runs scored per game for each team for all games within that season up to the date/game selected. I feel like I am almost there, I just need to get this date thing sorted out. Right now with the code as is, everything evaluates but I get this error twice;

Warning: Error in eval: do not know how to convert 'input$dates' to class “Date”

and this error twice;

Warning in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.Date") for "<"

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # Application title


  titlePanel("Predicting the winner of a Major League Baseball game"),

  sidebarLayout(

  sidebarPanel( 

    selectInput("season","1. Select an MLB Season",
                choices = list(2012,2013,2014,2015),
                selected = 2012),

    selectInput("var_1","2. Select the first team", 
      choices = c("ARI","ATL","BAL","BOS","CHC","CHW","CIN","CLE","COL","DET",
                "HOU","KCR","LAA","LAD","MIA","MIL","MIN","NYM","NYY","OAK",
                "PHI","PIT","SDP","SFG","SEA","STL","TBR","TEX","TOR","WSN"), 
      selected = "BAL"),


    selectInput("var_2","3. Select the second team",
      choices = c("ARI","ATL","BAL","BOS","CHC","CHW","CIN","CLE","COL","DET",
                "HOU","KCR","LAA","LAD","MIA","MIL","MIN","NYM","NYY","OAK",
                "PHI","PIT","SDP","SFG","SEA","STL","TBR","TEX","TOR","WSN"), 
      selected = "BOS"),

    uiOutput("dates"),

    sliderInput("bins",
                "Binwidth:",
                min = 1,
                max = 5,
                value = 2)

  ),

  #main panel
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("first_team_hist"),
    plotOutput("second_team_hist")
    )
  )))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(

  function(input, output) {

    mydf <- read.csv("batting_game_logs_merged.csv")


    inputData_1 <- reactive({

      filter(mydf,team == input$var_1 & season == input$season & date < as.Date(input$dates,format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

    })

    inputData_2 <- reactive({

      filter(mydf,team == input$var_2 & season == input$season & date < as.Date(input$dates,format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
    })

    output$dates <- renderUI({

      dates = mydf %>% filter(team == input$var_1 & opponent_team == input$var_2 & season == input$season) %>% select(date)
      selectInput("dates","Pick a Game Date", as.character(dates[[1]]))

    })

    output$first_team_hist <- renderPlot({

       myplot_1 <-  ggplot(inputData_1(), aes(x = team_batting_gamelogs.R)) + 
          geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), 
          binwidth = input$bins, fill = I("blue"),col = I("red")) +
          labs(title = paste("Runs Scored per game for",input$var_1), 
               x= "Runs Scored per Game", y = "Density")

       print(myplot_1)
    })

    output$second_team_hist<- renderPlot({

      myplot_2 <-  ggplot(inputData_2(), aes(x = team_batting_gamelogs.R)) + 
        geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), 
                       binwidth = input$bins, fill = I("blue"),col = I("red")) +
        labs(title = paste("Runs Scored per game for",input$var_2), 
             x= "Runs Scored per Game", y = "Density")

      print(myplot_2)

    })

  }
)
```

Thank you in advance for taking the time to review my problem.

-Josh

Comment: Did you try converting it to `Date` class with `as.Date`?

Comment: Yea, so the dates field from mydf is formatted as a date. however, in the output$dates function I have to change it to a character so that it shows up in the UI as a date, rather than a number, which was weird.

Comment: Then you probably just need to convert it back to the correct class right before you make a comparison against the other date-formatted vector

Comment: I did try that, if you look at the lines in the server.R section for inputData_1 and inputData_2 you can see that I convert back to date using as.Date and it still does not work correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing your problem is the initial `NULL` value of your `input$dates`. Your reactive environments `inputData_1/2` respond as soon as your UI is rendered (and they get their `selected` value). But no value has been assigned to `input$dates` yet, so your first run of these functions gets a `NULL`. Confirm that `as.Date(NULL)` yields exactly your error.

I advice you to make your reactive environments only listen to `input$dates`, i.e.

```
inputData_1 <- eventReactive(input$dates, {
  filter(mydf,team == input$var_1 & season == input$season & date < as.Date(input$dates,format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
})

inputData_2 <- eventReactive(input$dates, {
  filter(mydf,team == input$var_2 & season == input$season & date < as.Date(input$dates,format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
})
```

As far as I can see, you want computations to start only after inserting a date anyway.

Other possible fixes are to `isolate` the other variables or just add an `if(!is.null(input$dates)){ ... }` clause to handle `NULL` input.